# Using an encrypted SSL-Tunnel backwards

Tags: ssl, vpn, local-area-network

Is it possible to use an encrypted VPN-Tunnel backwards?
I need to connect from my companys LAN to a device which shares the local internet connection using the VPN on my Home-PC.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Best regards
Simon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A VPN has no direction, i.e. traffic flows in both directions. If you can reach an internal system at the LAN on the other end instead depends on routing and maybe firewall rules. This means depending on these (which are unknown) it might be possible or not.

Comment: Thanks, I asked, because I couldn't reach a device on my home LAN, but after trying a few things, I came to understand that it was my Windows Firewall, which was blocking the incoming traffic. I added a rule and it works perfectly. Thanks for the hint with the firewall.